# SICP - Multiplication through addition

Tags: lisp, racket, sicp

I am using the book SICP and attempting to solve this exercise:

> #### [1.2.4 Exponentiation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_sec_1.2.4)
>
> **Exercise 1.18.**  Using the results of exercises 1.16 and 1.17, devise
>   a procedure that generates an iterative process for multiplying two
>   integers in terms of adding, doubling, and halving and uses a
>   logarithmic number of steps

I am trying to solve this with the following code:

```
(define (double x) 
  (+ x x))

(define (halve x) 
  (floor (/ x 2)))

(define (* a b)
  (define (iter count accumulate)
    (cond ((= count 1) accumulate)
          ((even? a) (iter (halve count) (+ accumulate (double b))))
          (else empty)))
  (iter a 0))
```

As you might see, I am trying to deal with even numbers first.
I am using the [SICP wiki as my solutions-guide](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.18). They suggest some tests to see if the code works:

```
 (* 2 4) 
 (* 4 0)
```

What I do not get is that my code passes on these two first tests, dealing only with even numbers.

However, when I try some big numbers which are multiples of two, the code fails. I checked the result using Python.  For instance,

```
(IN PYTHON)

2**100  
>> 1267650600228229401496703205376  
2**98
>> 316912650057057350374175801344
a = 2**100
b = 2**98
a*b
>> 401734511064747568885490523085290650630550748445698208825344
```

When I use my function inside Dr. Racket with these values I get a different result:

```
(* 1267650600228229401496703205376 316912650057057350374175801344)
```

My result is: 63382530011411470074835160268800, which is wrong, as Python built-in functions suggest.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive step seems wrong, and what's that `empty` doing there? also, what happens if `b` is negative? this solution should work:

```
(define (mul a b)
  (define (iter a b acc)
    (cond ((zero? b) acc)
          ((even? b) (iter (double a) (halve b) acc))
          (else (iter a (- b 1) (+ a acc)))))
  (if (< b 0)
      (- (iter a (- b) 0))
      (iter a b 0)))
```

For example:

```
(mul 1267650600228229401496703205376 316912650057057350374175801344)
=> 401734511064747568885490523085290650630550748445698208825344
```